# Matlab Clipboard Precision - Format long -

Tags: matlab

I need to copy paste several matrix from matlab to excel so i did my researches and i've found a really amazing script called num2clip that brings the selected array to the clipboard.
The only problem is that the numbers format is short, when i would like it to be long. 
I suspect the "double" type used in the script but i'm still new to matlab so i do have some important lacks.

Here is the script that i've found, what do i have to do according to you in order to keep the long input format ?

```
function arraystring = num2clip(array)

function arraystring = num2clip(array)

%NUM2CLIP copies a numerical-array to the clipboard
%   
%   ARRAYSTRING = NUM2CLIP(ARRAY)
%   
%   Copies the numerical array ARRAY to the clipboard as a tab-separated
%   string.  This format is suitable for direct pasting to Excel and other
%   programs.
%   
%   The tab-separated result is returned as ARRAYSTRING.  This
%   functionality has been included for completeness.
%   
%Author: Grigor Browning
%Last update: 02-Sept-2005

%convert the numerical array to a string array
%note that num2str pads the output array with space characters to account
%for differing numbers of digits in each index entry
arraystring = num2str(array); 

%add a carrige return to the end of each row
arraystring(:,end+1) = char(10);

%reshape the array to a single line
%note that the reshape function reshape is column based so to reshape by
%rows one must use the inverse of the matrix
%reshape the array to a single line
arraystring = reshape(arraystring',1,prod(size(arraystring))); 

%create a copy of arraystring shifted right by one space character
arraystringshift = [' ',arraystring]; 

%add a space to the end of arraystring to make it the same length as
%arraystringshift
arraystring = [arraystring,' ']; 

%now remove the additional space charaters - keeping a single space
%charater after each 'numerical' entry
arraystring = arraystring((double(arraystring)~=32 |...
          double(arraystringshift)~=32) &...
          ~(double(arraystringshift==10) &...
          double(arraystring)==32) );

%convert the space characters to tab characters
arraystring(double(arraystring)==32) = char(9); 
format long e

%copy the result to the clipboard ready for pasting
clipboard('copy',arraystring);
```

Best regards.

Comment: so using the matlab function xlswrite doesn't work in your situation?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the line with:

```
arraystring = num2str(array) ;
```

to a line like that:

```
arraystring = num2str(array,'%15.15f') ;
```

---

This will give you the maximum precision you can reach with the `double` type (15 digits).

Look at the [`num2str`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) documentation for more custom format.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Hoki for your participation. 
I didnt had the time to go through all the documentation wich is great by the way. 
When i tried your solution, the copied data was all inserted on one cell, i just had to change :
     arraystring = num2str(array,'%15.15f') ;
to 
     arraystring = num2str(array,15) ;

Have a nice day !